# Keep a div shown unless i clicked anything out of it

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#input').focus(function() {
    $('#div').show();
}).blur(function(){
    $('#div').hide();
})
```

```css
#div {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='input'>
<div id='div'><a href='www.domain.com'>Don't Forget to check the rules.<a></div>
```

In my code here, I'm trying to show a div when focused but hide it while not focused

How can i keep the div shown when i click on it? Everytime i try to click on it, It goes hidden again, I want to make it possible to `hold` the mouse on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this.

```css
#div {
  opacity: 0;
}

#input:focus + #div {
  opacity: 1;
}

#div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='input'>
<div id='div'>
  <a href='www.domain.com'>Don't Forget to check the rules.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#input').focus(function() {
    $('#div').show();
}).blur(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div').hide();
}, 200); 
})
```

Comment: That would make the div available for only 200ms, And cannot be hold on mouse click. It would work with right click window, But will still disappear.